# URL appending for two times in JSP

Tags: jquery, jsp

Hi i am trying to pass an URL on a button click event in a jsp page using Jquery.
I used an ajax call for this. 
JSP:

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
<a class="btn btn-success" style="width: 100%" id='approve'>Approve</a>
</div>
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            //LIVEICON
            $('#approve').on('click',function(){
                alert("Click");
                $('#formeffortloading').attr(
                        {                       
                            action : "${loginbean.contextPath}/effortloading/approveraction"
                        });
            var postData = $('#formeffortloading').serializeArray();
            var formURL = $('#formeffortloading').attr("action");
            console.log(':: Called :: '+formURL);
             $.ajax(
            {
                url : 'effortloading/approveraction',
                type: "POST",
                data : postData,
                success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) 
                {
                    //data: return data from server
                    console.log(':: << Success data >> :: '+data+':: textStatus ::'+textStatus+':: persistResponse ::'+data.persistResponse);

                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) 
                {
                        //console.log(':: << failed data >> :: '+data);
                        console.log(':: << failed data >> :: '+jqXHR+':: textStatus ::'+textStatus+':'+errorThrown);
                    //if fails      
                }
            }); 
                var comment = $('#comments').val();
                if(($('#comments').val()!="")){                             
                    //alert(comment);
                    $('#successalert').html('<strong>Approved...!</strong>').show().fadeOut(5000); 

                    }
                else{

                    if($("#comments").val()==""){$('#comments').css({'background-color':'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.09)','border-color':'red'});$('#comments_er').css('display','block');}
                    //if($("#approver").val()==null){$('#approver').css({'background-color':'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.09)','border-color':'red'});$('#approver_er').css('display','block');}
                }
            });
        });
```

But when clicking the button the URL is appending for two times like this  **localhost:8081/Costing/effortloading/effortloading/approveraction**

Kindly tell me what is the problem..

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your current url for this page is `localhost:8081/Costing/effortloading`. That is why a relative url `effortloading/approveraction` which you have given in `ajax` is appending two times. You could do either one of this.

1) Put ajax url as `approveraction` so that `effortloading` will not be appended twice.

2) You can find the `origin` with JavaScript and then you can append `effortloading/approveraction`

eg: `url: window.location.origin + 'effortloading/approveraction'`

```
$.ajax({
  url: window.location.origin + 'effortloading/approveraction',
  type: "POST",
  data: postData,
  success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    //data: return data from server
    console.log(':: << Success data >> :: ' + data + ':: textStatus ::' + textStatus + ':: persistResponse ::' + data.persistResponse);

  },
  error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    //console.log(':: << failed data >> :: '+data);
    console.log(':: << failed data >> :: ' + jqXHR + ':: textStatus ::' + textStatus + ':' + errorThrown);
    //if fails      
  }
});
```

Comment: I tried the first method. But still its showing 404 error.

Comment: Second method is giving an error like "Syntax error on token "'effortloading/approveraction'", , expected after this token"

Comment: It looks like `,` is missing after the url. Are you following `window.location.origin + 'effortloading/approveraction',`? If possible post the browser console error that you are getting.

Comment: Now I am getting an error like "<< failed data >> :: [object Object]:: textStatus ::error:SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'open' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Invalid URL" in my console

Answer (score 0):

Your post url `'effortloading/approveraction'` is the relative path
Perhaps the path of your jsp file is `localhost:8081/Costing/effortloading/`, so your ajax url become `localhost:8081/Costing/effortloading/effortloading/approveraction`

Use the site root path or variable `formURL` of your javascript.

```
 $.ajax(
            {
                url : formURL,//<<<-------- Here
                type: "POST",
                data : postData,
...
```